# Why can I not comment?

Tags: discussion

This is really annoying. When trying to answer questions (e.g obtaining info), I have to "answer the question". However, without the information, I cannot. The 50 rep rule for commenting should be removed because its so annoying.

Comment: Edit some questions and gain some credits. you can gain some knowledge by doing so.

Answer (score 5):

"The 50 rep rule for commenting should be removed because its so annoying."

- It takes seconds to get 50 rep. The time you took to type this you could have used to answer several questions and get to 50 reputation.
- It prevents abuse.

... results in

- me disagreeing with you.

You are abusing the Ask Ubuntu site to post a complaint about the rules. A user worthy commenting on questions on Ask Ubuntu would have known to post this on META (or a truly useful user would have searched the questions on META and realise it has been asked and answered before).

I would rather see a threshold for posting questions...

Comment: +1 For the questions threshold :p

Comment: @Rinzwind - honestly, 50% of the people that came here would look only for answers and they would probably only have 1 karma